# Compare two dates OR compare two dates minus 8 hours

Tags: php

Ok, weird one.

Wrote a script to check XML feed if school is closed for my kids county. Each entry comes with an "effective date" node, which is the date the school closing announcement is effective.

What I was doing, was comparing if the effective date, is older than the current time, which means that after midnight, a closing on the current day would work. But what if they close school the evening/night beforehand?

I need to check if the effective date is greater than today, but starting at 4pm instead of midnight.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$date_effective = $announcement->date_effective;
// format of xml feed datetime - 2018-02-02 00:00:00.000000
$date = new DateTime($date_effective);
$now = new DateTime();
// Here is where I need help, not sure how to word this
// if($date < $now || $date < $now - '8 hours') {
if($date < $now) {
    // iterate through cases based on status
}
```

Comment: So you want to subtract some hours from `$now` and compare it with `$date`, right?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat yes exactly. $date is the constant, and I need to know if the current time is later than midnight of that date, or midnight of that date minus 8 hours (4pm previous day)

Comment: So why would you check if the current time is later than midnight of that date when you are already checking if the date is after 4 pm previous day? Midnight of the date will obviously be after 4 pm previous day.

Comment: Right now, school is closed tomorrow. The effective date is '2018-02-02 00:00:00.000000'. The current time is not greater than that date, so my script doesn't think that school is closed for tomorrow. If I compared the effective date to 4pm today, then it is greater, and would yield the correct case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [\DateTime::sub](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php) combined with a [\DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.createfromdatestring.php) representing the time difference:

```
$now  = new DateTime;
$then = (clone $now)->sub(DateInterval::createFromDateString('8 hours'));
if ($date < $now || $date < $then) {
    // ...
}
```

(Note the use of `clone`, because `sub` modifies the object on which it's called.)

Answer (score 2):

use `strotime` instead of that

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$date_effective = $announcement->date_effective;

$date = strtotime($date_effective);
// since 1 hr is 3600 secs so multiply this by 8 which result to 28800
$now = strtotime('now') - 28800; 

if($date < $now) {
  // iterate through cases based on status
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/947512)

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set` does not work the way you think it works on `strtotime`